# How to use crosstab/pivot with multi dimensions

Tags: python, csv, pandas, pivot-table, crosstab

I tried using pivot tables to have more than one values in the 'values' field  for the pivot_table function but it doesnt work, so im trying to see if i can do it with crosstabs. 
Here is my code

```
table=pandas.pivot_table(xl2, values='Applications', rows='Sub-Product',cols='Application Date',aggfunc=numpy.sum)
```

i get this when i export to csv.

```
  Sub-Product   11/1/12 11/2/12 11/3/12
    GP            190    207      65
    GPF           1391   1430     1269
```

In python, after converting it to a pivot table, the dtype is float64() and using

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

what i ultimately want is this output in csv:

```
Row Labels  11/1/2012   11/2/2012   11/3/2012
GP          
Acquisitions    164        168          54
Applications    190        207          65
GPF         
Acquisitions    1124       1142         992
Applications    1391       1430         1269
```

with a code along the lines of this (currently it doesnt work :/ ) :

```
table=pd.pivot_table(xl2, values=['Acquisitions','Applications'], rows=['Sub-Product'],cols=['Application Date'],aggfunc=np.sum)
```

But I can only get this:

```
Sub-Product ('Applications', Timestamp('2012-11-01 00:00:00', tz=None)) ('Applications', Timestamp('2012-11-02 00:00:00', tz=None)) ('Applications', Timestamp('2012-11-03 00:00:00', tz=None))
GP  190 207 65
GPF 1391    1430    1269
```

Any ideas on how crosstab can help? :S

---

This is the data in the csv file. I'm not sure why i cant get them into the proper dataframe format.

```
Application Date    Sub-Product Applications    Acquisitions
11/1/12             GP                1            1
11/1/12             GP                1            1
11/1/12             GP                1            1
11/1/12             GP                1            1
11/1/12             GPF               1            1
11/1/12             GPF               1            1
11/1/12             GPF               1            1
11/1/12             GPF               1            1
```

Comment: where do the other numbers come from? (The view you want isn't a standard way to look a DataFrames, although you *can* create a csv like that once you have the correct DataFrame...)

Comment: Andy, can i send u the original csv file so you can test it out?

Comment: Is it possible to just provide the first dozen lines or so (or however-many to reproduce the results above) and edit them in to your question ? :)

Comment: added a snippet of the csv file

Comment: Thanks for editing! Ah, I see. So you have created a DataFrame with `xl2 = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', sep='\s+')` ?

Comment: yup, actually just xl2 = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')

Comment: `xl = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')`   `xl2=DataFrame(xl)` @Andy

Comment: ok, and that bits working? (Note: you don't need to do DataFrame(xl) since it's already a DataFrame :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're really close to where you want to be.  `table.stack(0)` will move the first level of the column index to the row index.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: from StringIO import StringIO
In [3]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""\
   ...: Application-Date    Sub-Product       Applications    Acquisitions
   ...: 11/1/12             GP                1            1
   ...: 11/1/12             GPF               1            1
   ...: 11/2/12             GP                1            1
   ...: 11/2/12             GP                1            1
   ...: 11/2/12             GPF               1            1
   ...: 11/2/12             GPF               1            1
   ...: 11/3/12             GP                1            1
   ...: 11/3/12             GP                1            1
   ...: 11/3/12             GP                1            1
   ...: 11/3/12             GPF               1            1
   ...: 11/3/12             GPF               1            1
   ...: 11/3/12             GPF               1            1
   ...: """), sep='\s+', parse_dates=[0])
In [4]: table = df.pivot_table(values=['Acquisitions', 'Applications'],
   ...:                        rows='Sub-Product',
   ...:                        cols='Application-Date',
   ...:                        aggfunc=sum)
In [5]: table
Out[5]: 
                  Applications                          Acquisitions                        
Application-Date    2012-11-01  2012-11-02  2012-11-03    2012-11-01  2012-11-02  2012-11-03
Sub-Product                                                                                 
GP                           1           2           3             1           2           3
GPF                          1           2           3             1           2           3
In [6]: table.stack(0)
Out[6]: 
Application-Date          2012-11-01  2012-11-02  2012-11-03
Sub-Product                                                 
GP          Applications           1           2           3
            Acquisitions           1           2           3
GPF         Applications           1           2           3
            Acquisitions           1           2           3
```

Comment: @ Garrett, would you happen to know how i can group the dates by week?

Comment: try `ds = df.set_index('Application-Date')` to make a time series indexed dataframe, then `ds.groupby('Sub-Product').resample("W", how=sum).reset_index()`

Comment: ok, what if i only want to start on 2012/11/4 such that the first week will be 2012/11/4-2012/11/10, second week will be 2012/11/11-2012/11/17

Comment: think you want to pass `label='left', closed='left'` to resample().  the defaults for periods longer than a day are `label='right', closed='right'`.   see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#id3 for some details on resampling to daily and faster frequencies

Comment: And i want to group them by date, after they are transformed into pivot table

Comment: not sure I follow -- probably best to create a new Q, with sample output showing how you'd like them grouped.

Comment: here is the link to the new q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035536/how-to-use-groupby-weeks-for-a-pivot-table-created-in-pandas