# How to use pandas to group pivot table results by week?

Tags: python, sql, group-by, pandas

Below is a snippet of my pivot table output in .csv format after using pandas pivot_table function:

```
Sub-Product     11/1/12 11/2/12 11/3/12 11/4/12 11/5/12 11/6/12
GP  Acquisitions    164    168     54      72     203    167
GP  Applications    190    207     65      91     227    200
GPF Acquisitions    1124   1142    992    1053    1467   1198
GPF Applications    1391   1430   1269    1357    1855   1510
```

The only thing I need to do now is to use groupby in pandas to sum up the values by week for each Sub Product before I output it to a .csv file.

Below is the output I want, but it is done in Excel. The first column might not be exactly the same but I am fine with that. The main thing I need to do is to group the days by week such that I can get sum of the data to be by week. (See how the top row has the dates grouped by every 7 days). Hoping to be able to do this using python/pandas. Is it possible?

```
Row Labels   11/4/12 - 11/10/12       11/11/12 - 11/17/12
GP      
Acquisitions       926                        728
Applications       1092                       889
GPF     
Acquisitions       8206                       6425
Applications       10527                      8894
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tool you need is `resample`, which implicitly uses groupby over a time period/frequency and applies a function like mean or sum.

Read data.

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
      Sub-Product  11/1/12  11/2/12  11/3/12  11/4/12  11/5/12  11/6/12
GP   Acquisitions      164      168       54       72      203      167
GP   Applications      190      207       65       91      227      200
GPF  Acquisitions     1124     1142      992     1053     1467     1198
GPF  Applications     1391     1430     1269     1357     1855     1510
```

Set up a MultiIndex.

```
In [4]: df = df.reset_index().set_index(['index', 'Sub-Product'])

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
                    11/1/12  11/2/12  11/3/12  11/4/12  11/5/12  11/6/12
index Sub-Product                                                       
GP    Acquisitions      164      168       54       72      203      167
      Applications      190      207       65       91      227      200
GPF   Acquisitions     1124     1142      992     1053     1467     1198
      Applications     1391     1430     1269     1357     1855     1510
```

Parse the columns as proper datetimes. (They come in as strings.)

```
In [6]: df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
                    2012-11-01  2012-11-02  2012-11-03  2012-11-04  \
index Sub-Product                                                    
GP    Acquisitions         164         168          54          72   
      Applications         190         207          65          91   
GPF   Acquisitions        1124        1142         992        1053   
      Applications        1391        1430        1269        1357   

                    2012-11-05  2012-11-06  
index Sub-Product                           
GP    Acquisitions         203         167  
      Applications         227         200  
GPF   Acquisitions        1467        1198  
      Applications        1855        1510
```

Resample the columns (`axis=1`) weekly (`'w'`), summing by week. (`how='sum'` or `how=np.sum` are both valid options here.)

```
In [10]: df.resample('w', how='sum', axis=1)
Out[10]: 
                    2012-11-04  2012-11-11
index Sub-Product                         
GP    Acquisitions         458         370
      Applications         553         427
GPF   Acquisitions        4311        2665
      Applications        5447        3365
```

Comment: you can pass ``axis=1`` to resample, to avoid the double transposing

Comment: Thanks! however, what if i want data that is week beginning instead of week ending? For example, the date column remains as it is but all the data below the 2012-11-11 will shift to the left to be under 2012-11-04?

Comment: Read up on [anchored offsets](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets). Perhaps ``'W-SAT'`` will work for you (in place of ``'w'`` above).

Comment: resample has new syntax. It should now be: df.resample('w', axis =1).sum()